# why does the value of an imported constant change (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm importing an array called `CHART_CARDS` in a Vue component.  This is meant to provide the initial state for another array, called `chartCards`, which a user can change.

```
import { CHART_CARDS } from '~/constants/chartCards'

...

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      chartCards: []
    }
  },
  async created(){
    if (this.$auth.user.settings && this.$auth.user.settings.length) {
      this.chartCards = this.$auth.user.settings
    } else {
      this.chartCards = CHART_CARDS
    }
  }
}
```

So the data property chartCards is either taken from the imported variable or from a pre-existing database table.

Here's where things get weird: I have a method called reset, which is supposed to restore the chartCards variable to the value of the imported array:

```
     async reset () {
         console.log('going to reset.  CHART_CARDS looks like:')
         console.log(CHART_CARDS)
         this.chartCards = CHART_CARDS
         await this.updateCards()
         console.log('chart cards after updating:')
         console.log(this.chartCards)
     }
```

Somehow, `CHART_CARDS` is also changed when `chartCards` is updated.  The two console logs above print the same array, so the reset doesn't work.  `CHART_CARDS` is changed nowhere else in the code; all references to `CHART_CARDS` are shown in the above code.  How is its value being updated?

Comment: since `this.chartCards = CHART_CARDS` they're the same reference. so any change will be reflected in both vars.

Comment: @MarkusDresch .   what could I do to fix this?  I tried this.chartCards = Array.from(CHART_CARDS) , and it doesn't make a difference

Comment: i suspect you are modifying the objects inside the array. Array.from creates a shallow copy, resulting in a new array containing the same objects. if you indeed need a deep copy, one quick and dirty solution is to serialize/deserialize it with JSON.stringify/JSON.parse.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, your `CHART_CARDS` array probably contains objects, and you are most likely changing these objects somewhere in your code.

There is an easy way around this with some minor API tweaks.

**~/constants/chartCards.js**

```
export function getChartCards () {
  return [
    {...},
    {...},
    ...
  ]
}
```

**App.vue**

```
import { getChartCards } from '~/constants/chartCards'

...

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      chartCards: []
    }
  },
  async created(){
    if (this.$auth.user.settings && this.$auth.user.settings.length) {
      this.chartCards = this.$auth.user.settings
    } else {
      this.chartCards = getChartCards()
    }
  }
}
```

Since we're always creating a *new* array with *different* objects, changes made to one `chartCards` instance will not reflect in another.

If you *absolutely* want to stick with your current API, then that can potentially be achieved as well. You just need to create a deep-copy of your `CHART_CARDS` object before assigning it.

```
import { CHART_CARDS } from '~/constants/chartCards'

...

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      chartCards: []
    }
  },
  async created(){
    if (this.$auth.user.settings && this.$auth.user.settings.length) {
      this.chartCards = this.$auth.user.settings
    } else {
      this.chartCards = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(CHART_CARDS)) // This will not work if your CHART_CARDS has methods
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, clear answer.  Is there any reason to prefer one approach above the other?

Comment: Ideally, as much as possible you want to avoid usage of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`. For larger objects, it might be expensive to do so. In that regard, the first option is preferred. Additionally, the first option also gives you the flexibility of having methods in your `CHART_CARDS` object.